# How can I access the view function in a Django template tag?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

What it says on the tin: I want to be able to access either:

- the view function itself
- the view name (although this is less useful, I can probably use it to get back to the function)
- attributes of the view function

This needs to be accessed from within a template tag.

In short, what I'm trying to do is to mark up view functions with information that can be used by my base template to configure some of the view framing UI; set the title, for example, or populate a generic help object.  If someone can suggest a better way to do this, please feel free to provide that answer instead.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, when first implementing Django you sometimes have to change the way you think about your design, especially if you're coming from a language like PHP, ColdFusion, or another tag-based language where a lot of the functionality comes from within the template.

In a nutshell: *don't try to implement any complex programming logic within a django template*. if/then/else and loops are pretty much the extent of complexity that you should try to do directly within a template.

There are basically 3 ways to programmatically generate output within a template:

1. by creating the content in the view function. This is generally the most common way to do this. Nearly all queries will be set up within the view (although since they are "[lazy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation)" they often don't run until called within the template). Objects, dictionaries, lists, tuples, and simple strings can all be created within a view and sent to the template and accessed using [Django's dot notation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#variables). Some people pick and choose which variables they want sent through and use a dictionary (usually called `context`) to send them through. An easy (although less discriminating) option is just to send `locals()` which will send through every variable created within the function (as well as the parameters).
2. by implementing a function within an object sent to the template. An example would be a function you've defined for a model. If you created a function `most_recent_posts` for an `Author` model, you could use something like `{% for post in author.most_recent_posts %}`
3. through the use of [custom tags and templates](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/). This is often necessary when there is processing or formatting that needs to done on a variable and it wouldn't make sense to do that processing from within the view function. Although filters (function: take an input, modify it [with one argument if you wish] and return it) and are trivial to develop. Tags can be more complicated.

For your purposes, for example to create a "help object" on the page, you may be interested in a special kind of custom tag known as an [inclusion tag](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags). You call it like a normal custom tag: `{% show_help obj %}` and you create a template designed to output the data for that object. For example, let's say you wanted to implement a context-sensitive help system, and you just wanted it to pull Help objects from the database and output them. You'd create a tag thusly:

```
from help.models import Help
@register.inclusion_tag('/help/help.html')
def show_help(topic):
    help = Help.objects.get(topic__iexact=topic)
    return {
        'help': help
    }
```

And then you'd have a template for outputting the help content:

```
# /help/templates/help/help.html
<div class="help-widget">
<h2>{{ help.title }}</h2>
<p>{{ help.content }}</p>
</div>
```

In your template, you'd call the inclusion tag:

```
<form><fieldset>Delete Project</fieldset>
...
{% show_help "Deleting Project" %}
</form>
```

Comment: The only tricky part here is the nature of the template; the help link in question is going in a base template, and so I need to pass in the view's name. Putting that in the context in dozens of views is a pain in the ass; it seems to me that there must be a better way of doing this.

Comment: No, in that case you create a help block: `{% block help %}{% endblock help %}`. Then you put that block in each of the templates. Since the templates are (I hope!) different for each view, you can specify which help content should be displayed directly in that block.

Answer (score 2):

That's what the template context dictionary contains.  It should contain "the title, for example, or populate a generic help object."

```
def myViewFunction( request ):
    # whatever
    return render_to_response( template,
        { 'title': "Title of this view's page",
          'help': someHelpObject, },
          'name': 'myViewFunction',
          'attribute': 'some attribute of myViewFunction',
     )
```

Answer (score 1):

A view function doesn't have any special status in Django.

A template can be rendered anywhere: in a view, inside a templatetag, in a model method, in a utility function... so it's not even clear what you would want to access. But in any case, the general principle is that if you want access to something in a template, you should pass it into the template context.

Answer (score 0):

If u need to pass some context which is repeated every time, and is to be mentioned in the context of the view everytime a view is written.

It can be done in a far better way by using context_processors. This link will provide you the rest of the required information. Fell free to communicate if any query.

[Definition of Context Processors](http://www.import-awesome.com/how-requestcontext-works-and-why-its-awesome)